# Searching dictionary for max value then grabbing associated key

Tags: python

I need help grabbing the maximum value from a dictionary. I have a dictionary of {num : [state,value] ...} and need to grab everything associated with the highest value.

```
#find max value in dictionary
td = {0: ['b',3], 1: ['b',6], 4: ['b',2], 3: ['b',5] }
#In this example td dict, I want to grab the key and state associated with the highest value, 6. I want to grab "1: ['b',6]"
print td
print td.keys()
print td.values()
maxval = max([v for k,[s,v] in td.iteritems()])
print maxval #correctly prints 6
```

Comment: Are you certain that the maximum v is only reached for one (k,s,v) triplet?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just change your `max()` comprehension to yield tuples with the value as the first element:

```
>>> max((v, k, s) for k, (s, v) in td.iteritems())
(6, 1, 'b')
```

So your code might look something like this:

```
maxval, maxnum, maxstate = max((v, k, s) for k, (s, v) in td.iteritems())
```

Comment: +1 but I think you should explain the 'magic' (about element-wise ordering on tuples)

Comment: ok Great! So max() looks at the first element in a tuple/list. What is the difference between k, (s, v) and k, [s, v]? I never use tuples, always lists. I guess the habit developed from trying to modify a tuple on accident then realizing lists can function as tuples that can be modified. Is there ever a reason I wouldn't want to use a list where a tuple could be used?

Comment: To explain getting the max of a sequence of tuples, tuples (and other sequences) are compared lexicographically; the first items are compared; if they are the same then the second items are compared, and so on.  You can see this in the [Sorting How To](http://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting) documentation.  As for using a tuple instead of a list for the sequence unpacking, it doesn't really make a difference here.  I use tuples out of habit in sequence unpacking but it might be more appropriate to use a list since that mimics the original data structure.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> td = {0: ['b',3], 1: ['b',6], 4: ['b',2], 3: ['b',5] }
>>> max(td, key=lambda k:td[k][1])
1  ## This is the key with the maximum "value"
```

Of course you can also get the value like this

```
>>> td[max(td, key=lambda k:td[k][1])]
['b', 6]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print max(td.items(), key = lambda item: item[1][1])
```

The key parameter takes a function, and if used it will produce the values that maximizes that function.